# How do I get JSON feed from Google Blogger without callback function?

Tags: java, android, json, blogs, blogger

I want to get JSON feed from Google Blogger for [this blog](http://softwarehub3.blogspot.co.ke). I have done some research and found [this solution](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/blogger_sample). However, JSON feed is being loaded fine but it has a call back function that wont load without. I want to parse this JSON feed using Android Volley. How do I go about it, or how do I handle this call back function with android `JsonObjectRequest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hard research I have found solution to this question. I got solution here [Here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/getting-json-from-blogger-blog). From above question I was getting the javascript json feed instead of actual feed. to get json feed use this link: https://your_blog_url/feeds/posts/default?alt=json. For example in my case I I have:
https://softwarehub3.blogspot.co.ke/feeds/posts/default?alt=json. 
Just that